# Skip a char in string without stop with sscanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm asking if I can use sscanf (scanf in general) to read a single character out to a string without reassembly, in C.

I tried multiple patterns without any success.

```
char a_word[10] = "a_word";
char b_word[10];

sscanf (a_word, "%%%", b_word);
```

```
b_word should contain: "a word".
```

As I pointed out just above, sure I could read in two separate chars and then strcat(), but can I avoid that.

Specifically, can I do it with just some tricky %format_specifier in one single char[] destination?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't. Either read the whole string, and replace the unwanted character with a space (my recommendation); Or read character by character and append to the destination, replacing the unwanted characters as you read them.

Comment: For your case, where you already have the string in an array, either method would work. But instead of reading input, copy the string. Either using `strcpy` for the first variant, or character by character for the second.

Comment: Or maybe you're looking for a regular expression library, much more flexible than the scanf formats.

Comment: Is your purpose to replace underscores with spaces?

Comment: _"Tricky %format_specifier"_ is a bad idea; `scanf` and friends are tricky enough. Unless you have some other concerns not presented in your question, it seems like simply looping over strings to replace `_` characters with space characters would be the better choice.

Comment: It was just as general learning, not specific needing. I'm exercising with reading into files (so fprintf really) and I was 90% self conscious this was not possible but I wanted it certified by expert people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

You can use`"%[^_]_%[^_]"` to match the prefix (`"a"`) and suffix (`"word"`) which requires two string arguments to write the result.  You need the length of the prefix to figure out where to write the change (from `_` to  ) and the 2nd string into `b_word`.  You can either extract that length ahead of time (`sscanf()`, `strchr()` or `strcspn()`) or split it into two `sscanf()` calls.  This only works if you have 0 or 1 of the `_`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a_word[10] = "a_word";
    char b_word[10];
    int rv = sscanf(a_word, "%[^_]_", b_word);
    if(rv) b_word[rv++] = ' ';
    sscanf(a_word + rv, "%[^_]", b_word + rv);
    printf("%s\n", b_word);
}
```

Write a function instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strreplace(char *s, char from, char to) {
    while(*s++) if(*s == from) *s = to;
}

int main(void) {
    char a_word[10] = "a_word";
    char b_word[10];
    strcpy(b_word, a_word);
    strreplace(b_word, '_', ' ');
    printf("%s\n", b_word);
}
```

Comment: @M.M Where does it say it's implementation defined? I can see it neither from cppreference nor N3096. What I can see is that if it contains a `-` with some additional conditions it is implementation defined, but that should not apply here.

Comment: @WeijunZhou It seems to be documented in C17 7.21.6.2.

Comment: The scanset directives, including the circumflex, are defined by the standard and have been since C89. Using a dash in a scanset position other than the first (after any circumflex) or last is implementation-defined to allow for scanset ranges in some implementations, e.g., `%[0-9]` or `%[^0-9]`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou you are right, I mixed up two things